# How do I export bookmarks from Firefox v118 on Mac?

Tags: firefox, bookmarks, export, macos-sonoma

How do I export my bookmarks to HTML from Firefox on MacBook? I am using macOS Sonoma and FF 118. I have done this lots of times on FF for Windows but the Mac is different.

Comment: What does this look like on the Mac : Menu *Bookmarks > Organize bookmarks > Import and Backup > Backup*, where one can export as JSON?

Comment: @harrymc On the Mac it is Menu *Bookmarks > Manage bookmarks* and then the screen is displayed similar to Windows but with no *Import and Backup* option

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you go to the menu in the top right (3 little lines), and then click Bookmarks, then Manage bookmarks on the bottom of the list, it should open the "Library". Then there should be a button on the top that looks like an "Up and Down" arrows:

[image]

You click that and a dropdown appears that has an Export Bookmarks to HTML button, which once saved allows you to import them wherever you wish,

Source: https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/export-firefox-bookmarks-to-backup-or-transfer#firefox:mac:fx120